# Verwendung von "sich mit etwas erklären"

Tags: word-usage, verb, reflexive

Aus [*Spiegel-Online*](http://www.spiegel.de/politik/deutschland/wolfgang-schaeuble-bezeichnet-pegida-als-phaenomen-der-altersgesellschaft-a-1013339.html):

> Wolfgang Schäuble **erklärt sich Pegida mit der demografischen Entwicklung Deutschlands**: Die Anti-Islam-Bewegung habe auch entstehen können, weil es immer mehr Ältere ohne finanzielle Sorgen gäbe, sagte der Finanzminister dem SPIEGEL.

Warum wird "erklären" hier in die Reflexivform gesetzt? [Diesem Wörterbuch](http://dictionary.reverso.net/german-english/erklaren) zufolge muss man in der Reflexiv-Verwendung die erklärte Sache als Subjekt des Satzes stellen, nicht die erklärende Person.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Es handelt sich um dieselbe Konstruktion wie z.B.:

> Ich erkläre Dir etwas [mittels etwas]. 
>   ->W. Schäuble erklärt den Bürgern Pegida [mit der...].

Nur dass das (Dativ-)Objekt hier identisch mit dem Subjekt ist:

> ->W. Schäuble erklärt sich (selbst) Pegida [mit der...].

Comment: Ein Reflexivpronomen ist IMMER eine echte Reflexivform. Wäre schön, wenn du das "echte" zumindest in Anführungsstriche setzen könntest. Oder am besten ganz weg.

Comment: Frage mich auch, was ich *eigentlich* sagen wollte... danke für den Hinweis. Habe den Satz entfernt, bis ich mich erinnern kann!

Comment: Das ist nicht vollkommen richtig. Wie fast immer hat auch hier die reflexive Form eine leicht andere Bedeutung als die transitive Form mit Objekt=Subjekt.

Comment: @Toscho... reflexive ist immer automatisch auch transitiv. Die beiden sollte man nicht gegenüber stellen. Ausserdem hat der Bedeutungsunterschied mit der Reflexivität wenig zu tun sondern schlicht mit der Tatsache, dass unterschiedliche Objekte unterschiedliche Bedeutungen "triggern" können. "Ich streiche eine Stelle.", "Ich streiche einen Zaun.". Die Frage ist nur, ob man beide Beudetungen als Varianten oder de facto als zwei Verben verstehen will. Im reflexiven Fall sind es meist Varianten.

Comment: @Emanuel Vielleicht benutze ich die Begriffe hier etwas falsch, weil ich manche grammatikalischen Fachbegriffe in anderen Sprachen kennen gelernt habe, die aber auch andere grammatikalische Modelle haben. Transitiv bedeutet, imho, dass das Verb ein Nicht-präpositional-Objekt verlangt. Reflexiv bedeutet, imho, dass das Prädikat aus einem Verb und konjugationsabhängigen Partikel abhängt, der aussieht wie dekliniertes Personalpronomen. Z.B. würde ich in `Ich sehne mich.` das `mich` nicht als Objekt bezeichnen.

Comment: @Toscho.... meintest du "Partikel besteht"? Nach der Definition liegt in "Ich wasche mich. " keine Reflexivität vor, da es sich ja hier klar um ein Objekt handelt. Ich weiß, dass bei Reflexivität oft versucht wird irgendwelche Trennungen vorzunehmen, aber das führt zu mehr Verwirrung als es löst. Zumal auch fest reflexive Phrasen wohl einst "normal" reflexiv waren.

Answer (score 1):

Das verlinkte Wörterbuch ist unvollständig.

`sich erklären` hat eine weitere Bedeutung, die der nichtreflexiven Form mit wissenschaftlicher Bedeutung entspricht.

> Jemand erklärt sich einen Sachverhalt.

Dies bedeutet, dass jemand den Sachverhalt selbst hinterfragt hat (möglicherweise auf Anstoß von außen hin) und folgende Erklärung gefunden hat.

**Achtung:** Die nichtreflexive Form `erklären` wird umgangssprachlich zumeist in der Bedeutung `erläutern` benutzt. Das ist *nicht* die wissenschaftliche Bedeutung, die auf eine objektive Begründung objektiver Beobachtungen auf Grundlage wissenschaftlicher Gesetze und Modelle abzielt.